# Finding duplicate rows python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, duplicates

I have `timestamp` and `id` variables in my dataframe (`df`)

```
timestamp                    id
2016-06-09 8:33:37           a1  
2016-06-09 8:33:37           a1  
2016-06-09 8:33:38           a1
2016-06-09 8:33:39           a1
2016-06-09 8:33:39           a1
2016-06-09 8:33:37           b1
2016-06-09 8:33:38           b1
```

Each `id` can't have two timestamps. I have to print these duplicate timestamps for each `id`. In my above case, the output should be for rows 1,2,4,5

The following code will give the duplicate `timestamp`

```
set([x for x in df['timestamp'] if df['timestamp'].count(x) > 1])
```

How to consider `id` along with `timestamp` to have the duplicate rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to find all duplicates then use the `duplicated` method. It only works on the columns. On the other hand `df.index.duplicated` works on the index. Therefore we do a quick `reset_index` to bring the index into the columns.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.loc[df.duplicated(keep=False)]

    index               id
0   2016-06-09 8:33:37  a1
1   2016-06-09 8:33:37  a1
3   2016-06-09 8:33:39  a1
4   2016-06-09 8:33:39  a1
```

If you just wish to remove duplicates there is the DataFrame method `drop_duplicates`.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop_duplicates() # keep='first' by default.

    index               id
0   2016-06-09 8:33:37  a1
2   2016-06-09 8:33:38  a1
3   2016-06-09 8:33:39  a1
5   2016-06-09 8:33:37  b1
6   2016-06-09 8:33:38  b1
```

If you wish to get back your old index then set_index using the default columns name 'index' for either of the above then simply use.

```
df.set_index('index')

                    id
index               
2016-06-09 8:33:37  a1
2016-06-09 8:33:38  a1
2016-06-09 8:33:39  a1
2016-06-09 8:33:37  b1
2016-06-09 8:33:38  b1
```

The above methods allow you choose whether to keep the first, last or none of the duplicates by setting the `keep` attribute to `'first'`, `'last'` or `False`. So to remove all duplicates in `df` then use `keep=False`.

Comment: any change in this solution? `ix` is depreciated?

Comment: use `loc` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get mask of all duplicates values per group by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html). Last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.groupby(['id'])['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False)))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool

print (df[df.groupby(['id'])['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False))])
            timestamp  id
0 2016-06-09 08:33:37  a1
1 2016-06-09 08:33:37  a1
3 2016-06-09 08:33:39  a1
4 2016-06-09 08:33:39  a1
```